# Set Chosen value from option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a form which uses the Chosen dropdown. If the option the user wants is not available then they can show a modal with a form to add a new option. After the new option is submitted then the modal closes and the data stays in the fields and the chosen option is selected.

How do I set the chosen option selected by the text with jquery/JS. I wont know the value as its an id that is added in the database

```
$('#save_town').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var town_name = $('#new_town').val();
    var region_id = $('#new_region').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {town_name: town_name, region_id: region_id},
        url: '{/literal}{$base_url}{literal}settings/towns/do-add',
        success: function(result){
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function(){
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your script currently closes the modal dialog and reloads the location, so you won't be able to update your selection by javascript. Do I get you right, and you want to replace this behavior with an automaticly added new option which should also be selected?

Comment: Yes, but i think i need to reload to since the chosen options are taken from the db and need to reload - maybe I am wrong

Comment: Depends on your server response - if the response contains the chosen options (as an html fragment or a JSON string) you could simply update the select field without reloading the complete page.

Comment: Well the towns/do-add actually redirects to a different page because it is actually part of an admin section. If I could get selecting a chosen option with the text rather than the value i'd be sorted

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure I understand your question correctly, but maybe thats an solution:

```
$('option').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "goodby"){
        $(this).attr('selected','selected');
    }
});
```

with this, you can select an option by its text.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/TQnTy/

Comment: That will work with select boxes but I need it to work with Chosen.js Not sure if I can do it without populating the boxes via ajax in the first place

Comment: hm, you could do this:
don´t reload the page, instead, add the new option to the select field (and select it), after that call $("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated"); (see chosen.js docs) and chosen will pickup the new option.

If you need, I can write you an js example